# Decision tree intuition for one hot encoded data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

In attempting to understand how scikit decision tree behaves for onehot encoded data I have following :

```
X = [[1,0,1] , [1,1,1]]
Y = [1,2]

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy')
clf = clf.fit(X, Y)

print(clf.predict([1,0,1]))
print(clf.predict([1,1,1]))

print(clf.predict_proba([1,0,1]))
print(clf.predict_proba([1,1,1]))
```

Which returns :

```
[1]
[2]
[[ 1.  0.]]
[[ 0.  1.]]
```

Reading doc for predict_proba http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.html#sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeClassifier.predict_proba states following should be returned :

> p : array of shape = [n_samples, n_classes], or a list of n_outputs
>   such arrays if n_outputs > 1. The class probabilities of the input
>   samples. The order of the classes corresponds to that in the attribute
>   classes_.

Probability of correctness for given input value should be returned ?
How return values [[ 1.  0.]] , [[ 0.  1.]] correspond to class probabilities for input samples ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For instance `clf.predict_proba([1,0,1])` gives the following:

```
[[         1.                          0.        ]]                # sample 1
#          ^                           ^
# probability for class 1     probability for class 2
```

So the prediction says the probability of this sample `[1,0,1]` to be class 1 is `1`, to be class 2 is `0`. So the prediction should be `1` which is the same as `clf.predict([1,0,1])` gives you. This could also be other values for instance `[[0.8, 0.2]]`, so the class with the largest probability is considered as the predicted value.